# parse json and output in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to parse a json file and output in html by using javascript

here is my json file

```
{"quiz":[
    {
        "quizName":"Quiz 1",
        "question": [
            {
                "text": "1+1?",
                "choiceA": "1",
                "choiceB": "2",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "quizName":"Quiz 2",
        "question": [
            {
                "text": "2+2?",
                "choiceA": "3",
                "choiceA": "4",
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

here is my html

```
<body>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    var output="<ul>";
    for (var i in data.quiz) {
        output+="<li>" + data.quiz[i].quizName+"</li>";
    }

    output+="</ul>";
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
 });
   </script>
</body>
```

I want to display all the "quizName" in a list format like this

Quiz 1

Quiz 2

But by code doesn't output anything.

I am new to json and javascript, I don't know whether the json file is not correct or the javascript is not correct. Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think that one of those is not correct? What does your JavaScript console say? What happens if you add `console.log` statements to trace which bits of the code execute?

Comment: This is jQuery, not JavaScript.

Comment: @shmuli — Nonsense, jQuery is a JavaScript library. All jQuery is JavaScript (although the reverse is not true).

Comment: Please explain the problem you're having.

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ - Parse error on line 9:

Expecting 'STRING' - you have trailing commas which is a Bad Thing

Comment: @Quentin it output nothing

Answer (score 3):

You can't have commas after the last items of an object in a JSON file.

Change:

```
"choiceB": "2",
```

To this:

```
"choiceB": "2"
```

Do the same for `choiceA": "4",`

Comment: I also want to get a list of all question "text", do you know how to write it?

Comment: I think you could just select it the same way you did `data.quiz[i].quizName`. Something like `data.quiz[i].question.text` instead and format it as part of your `<li>` as you'd like. Though I'm not sure if I understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

if u r not sure with the Json is right or wrong you can check here online [json Parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/)   or  [jsonEditor](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/)

you have extra commas

this is the correct Json

```
{"quiz":[
  {
    "quizName":"Quiz 1",
    "question": [
        {
            "text": "1+1?",
            "choiceA": "1",
            "choiceB": "2"
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "quizName":"Quiz 2",
    "question": [
        {
            "text": "2+2?",
            "choiceA": "3",
            "choiceB": "4"
        }
    ]
  }
]}
```

ALso parsing it REFER  [parsing in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srivaish/UYHx7/1/)

Hope this Helps

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra commas in your json file at line numbers 9 and 19.

Answer (score 0):

All you need it's do one more loop..

```
var output="<ul>";
for (var i in dataset) {
    for (var j in dataset[i])
    {
    output+="<li>" + dataset[i][j].quizName+"</li>";
    }
}

output+="</ul>";
document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
```

here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/baximilian/qpJjN/

Comment: thanks, but also what if I want to display "text" "ChoiceA" and "ChoiceB" for the first quiz, what should I write?

Comment: @user2184612 the simplest way to do this you can see on updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/baximilian/qpJjN/2/ but you can optimize this.